# Why isn't justify-content centering my divs?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to center two divs inside the daddy div horizontally.

Daddy div is set to `flex-direction: column` as I want the child divs one below another, but at the center of the page.

`justify-content: center;` should do it but not working.

I finally made it work with `align-self`, but any explanation why this much code is not enough to center the divs inside?

Here is my code:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="child-1">HI</div>
    <div class="child-2">WE BUILD AWESOME STUFF</div>
</div>

.main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Main vs Cross Axis

Consider the *main axis* and *cross axis* of a flex container:

[image]
                                                                                                                       <sup>Source: [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#box-model)</sup>

In the image above, the main axis is horizontal and the cross axis is vertical. These are the default directions for a flex container.

However, these directions can be easily switched with the [`flex-direction`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-flex-direction) property.

```
/* main axis is horizontal, cross axis is vertical */
flex-direction: row;
flex-direction: row-reverse;

/* main axis is vertical, cross axis is horizontal */    
flex-direction: column;
flex-direction: column-reverse;
```

(The cross axis is always perpendicular to the main axis.)

---

### justify-content property (works on main axis only)

The `justify-content` property aligns flex items along the main axis of the flex container.

In other words, when your container is `flex-direction: row`, that makes the main axis horizontal. `justify-content: center` will work as you expect.

But you've set the container to `flex-direction: column`. This means that the main axis is now vertical, and `justify-content` will position flex items up/down, not left/right.

Since you have no extra height in your example, you won't notice anything different; `justify-content` has no space to work. (Unlike width, which block elements fill 100% by default, heights must be defined. Otherwise, elements default to `auto` – the height of the content.) But give the container some height and see what happens.

---

### align-* properties (work on cross axis only)

The `align-self`, `align-items` and `align-content` properties operate on a flex container's cross axis (again, always perpendicular to the main axis).

Because your main axis is vertical, the `align-*` properties will align flex items left/right. That's why `align-self` worked to center your divs.

---

> Quick Summary: Depending on the `flex-direction`, the main axis and cross axis switch, taking their assigned properties with them.

---

### Solution

If your goal is minimal code, here's all you need:

```
.main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
```

---

More details: [In CSS Flexbox, why are there no "justify-items" and "justify-self" properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276)